# Oven stops heating

Tags: oven

Oven is a Whirlpool Model # WFG371LVB1 Serial # R00415666 and is about 10 years old.

When cooking for less than 20 minutes, there is no issue and the oven will stay heating for the entire time. But anything past 20 minutes and it will eventually stop heating. The oven is still on and displays the set temperature (example 425 degrees).

You can hear it clicking and trying to turn back on, just like when you initially turn on the oven and it starts heating. However, it eventually clicks off and no longer heats.

I'm not a handy man and will need to hire someone who can fix the problem. But just wanted to see if anyone could possibly identify the problem and give me an idea of what it will cost to repair the oven.

Comment: +1 for including the make and model without having to be prompted! You'd be _shocked_ at how many people don't think of that...

Comment: Enter diagnostic mode, usually by pressing cancel, cancel, start. Cycle through functions with +/-  this should give the error code if any.

Comment: Possible reasons are a faulty thermostat or printed circuit board. The cost of either are reasonable if purchased on-line. The technician will jack the price up because it's an Original Equipment of the Manufacturer (OEM). They'll also charge for their time and travel: $100 first hour and $50 for each additional hour + parts ($100). This pricing is for my location (Los Angeles, CA). Prices vary depending on your location.

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to give a definitive answer as to what the oven issue is or how much it will cost to fix without the oven being properly inspected by a professional.

I checked the web for info and here is what I found:  An oven that has issues heating is a common one (meaning that perhaps the cost to fix won't be too extortionate?).

The cause of this issue could be a burned fuse or a faulty relay board (that is tripping when it gets to a certain temp).

A fault in the main control board may be the reason this also. Or it could be an issue with the igniter (common with gas ovens).

I got this info from https://www.electrafixbc.ca/appliances/stove.html

I hope you get it figured out.

Comment: These statements should be comments because they are not actual answers to the OP's question.